# Macbook Pro - Removing Thermal Sensor, problems?

Tags: cpu, macbook, macbook-pro, fan, temperature

I'll try be brief. My macbook pro 2008 unibody, kept asking me to shut down, if you kept pressing cancel it would wait, and ask again... and repeat until it just turned it self off. After it would boot to different times then shut down. But never functional. It seemed like a thermal problem, so cleaned fans, changed thermal paste, still same problem. I disconnected the thermal sensor and now it works fine.

Right, the only problem I can really imagine is the fans wearing out i've set the base speed to 3,500 RPM (max in Fan Control). Too poor to get it looked at/fixed by a professional, also too poor for new Logic Board.

TLDR: I removed my thermal sensor, what problems are going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have disconnected all three internal thermal sensors deliberately in two different early 2008 MacBook Pros, (Model Identifier MacBook Pro4,1).  I can confirm that the Firmware will make the internal Fans run at 100%.

This is actually very beneficial as this way the MacBook Pro is being cooled the maximum amount by the internal fans from the moment it powers on.  This is well before the operating system even loads.  This is also the case when using Target Disk Mode or a NetBoot etc.  I also use heavy duty external cooling pad fans to help cool then from the outside as well.

The only possible downside of having the internal thermal sensors disconnected is that the internal fans will wear out sooner and the MacBook Pro will be noisier. Also, obviously Apple's Hardware test will report that the thermal sensors are not functioning either.

Personally, I'd much rather put up with the fan noise and  replace worn out internal fans than a blown Nvidia GPU, something which is well known to happen in these MacBook Pros from overheating.

In fact, one of these 2 MacBook Pros is one I have brought back from the 'dead' three times using the 'blanket trick' and without having its internal thermal disconnected so that the internal fans run at 100% as soon as its put into Target Disk Mode the Nvidia GPU fails, so doing this has kept it alive!